# Duplicate Entry in ManyToMany for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: hibernate

I recently received some help creating a ManyToMany relation. The code seems to work. My table looks like:

```
house_id is PK and NN
username is PK and NN
```

and may appear as

```
house_id   username
  41            t
  41            tea
  40            tea
```

However, every time I add something to this table it works the first time, but when I try to add something else I get a duplicate error on '' with primary key.
When I add

```
house_Id 22 and username 2
```

it works the first time. But if right after that I add

```
house_id 24 and username 2
```

hibernate will give me an exception:

```
ERROR: Duplicate entry 'tea-22' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I don't understand why Hibernate complains about 'tea-22' when I already put that one in there successful, and now trying to save 'tea-24' instead. Like if there's some cache that haven't flushed out 'tea-22'.

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
private String username;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;



@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "house_user_association", joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "house_id", referencedColumnName = "projectId")})  
        private Set<House> houses = new HashSet<>();

public User() {
}

public User(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public Collection<Houses> getHouses() {
    return houses;
}

public void setHouses(Collection<Marker> houses) {
    this.houses = houses;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
}
```

House class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="house")
public class House{


    private String address; 

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookmarks")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long projectId; 

    public House() {

    }

    public House(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public long getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(long projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Servlet method:

```
 Session session1 = null;
        String output = "";
        boolean contains = true;
        Long houseId = null;
        House house = null;

try {

            String add = request.getParameter("houseId");
            System.out.println("Trying to insert: " + add);
            session1 = hiber.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session1.beginTransaction();
            house = (House) session1.get(Marker.class, Long.parseLong(add));
            houseId = house.getProjectId();
            System.out.println("fetched houseID: " + houseId);
            session1.getTransaction().commit();
            session1.close();

            for (Iterator<House> iterator = SessionUser.getHouses().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                House houseIterate = iterator.next();
                if (houseIterate.getProjectId() == houseId) {
                    contains = false;
                    System.out.println(houseIterate.getProjectId());
                }
            }   
            System.out.println(contains);
            if(contains){
                session1 = hiber.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session1.beginTransaction();
                System.out.println("fetched houseID: " + house.getProjectId());
                SessionUser.getHouses().add(house);
                session1.merge(SessionUser);
                session1.flush();
                session1.getTransaction().commit();

                output = "[" +"/" +marker.getLat() + "/" + marker.getLng() + "/" + marker.getProjectId() + "/" + marker.getAddress()+ "/" +"]";
                out.print(output);  
                System.out.println(output);     
                System.out.println("Closing hibernate Session");    
            }
            if(!contains){
                System.out.println("Already contains"); 
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            house = null;
            houseId = null;
            contains = true;
            System.out.println("Test"); 
            if(session1 != null){
                session1.close();
            }       
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the source code for the part where you create or update the item?

Comment: Yes I edited my post with it

Comment: In your example, there are two lines with 'housId = 41', that can't be right, can it?

Comment: Am I correct to think that 'contains' means 'the list does not contain'?

Comment: yes it should be right that it can appear more than once. Since I want houses to have many users. In my servlet contains is a boolean, I set it to false if my user tries to add a house with the same id